# The os.walk method not work properly after converting to an EXE

Tags: python, exe, os.walk

I use the os.walk method to get the absolute path of all of the HTML files under the specified path. When I run it as a python script I have no problems, but after converting it to an EXE(Use Pyinstaller), It can't work properly.

Have any matters need attention after converting it to an EXE, or I'm missing something?

```
import os
import csv
from os import listdir
from os import walk
from os.path import isfile, isdir, join


def get_html_file_path(file_path):
    htmlfile = []
    for root, dirs, files in walk(file_path):
        for f in files:
            # print(f)
            try:
                pass
                if f.split('.')[1] == "html":
                    fullpath = join(root, f)
                    htmlfile.append(fullpath)
            except:
                pass
    return htmlfile


full_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
file_path = os.path.dirname(full_path)

aaa = get_html_file_path(file_path)

print(aaa)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it can't work properly"? What's supposed to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: Yes, after converting to an EXE with PyInstaller, `__file__` won't point to a sensible path. What do you expect your program to do? Why does it need to look at HTML files near the executing module?

Comment: As an aside, your program simplifies pretty much to `glob.glob(f"{file_path}/**.html", recursive=True)`...

Comment: @AKX Thanks for your provide the key point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sys.executable`](https://pyinstaller.org/en/v4.2/runtime-information.html#using-sys-executable-and-sys-argv-0) instead for your purpose of obtaining the base path of the main executable:

```
import sys

file_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
```

Comment: This problem has been solved after apply information that your provide. Thanks!